# Why does my js not run when when navigating back on Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, vue.js

When I enter a page by navigating back from another page on the same site half of the functions don't run, with no errors given on the console. If I then refresh the page, everything works fine.

As an example I added several console log's in the top level of my main js file but nothing was logged out

How does Safari handle load events and run js files differently on pages loaded this way?

This only happens on pages using vue components

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by reloading the page on back navigation:

```
 window.onpageshow = function(event) {
      if (event.persisted) {
       window.location.reload() ;
   }
};
```

Comment: It works! I got a similar problem. I'm using vuejs and when clicking the go-back button of safari it stops loading the main js. It works perfectly on chrome and firefox. If anyone got the similar problem, just try to add the above script into index.html. I think it's caused by browser cache.